# My deleted question turns purple, and does not dissapear -- why?

Tags: support

My deleted question turns purple, and does not disappear -- why?  Is there a time lag or voting that must occur?

---

Sorry-now I see the answers are in:
[How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

See the accepted answer for even more info.

Comment: You still can your own deleted questions yourself, that's it.

Comment: Others can't see it?

Comment: _"Others can't see it?"_ Not below 10k rep ...

Comment: The down vote might be for lack of research: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that  *Deleted posts are usually not physically deleted (that is, removed from the system); they're just hidden (AKA soft-deleted).* and *Moderators, and normal users with >=10k reputation, see all deleted posts that they have links to.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It has been deleted and now is only visible to those with the URL of the question **and** more than 10,000 reputation on the site.

Regular users won't see the link in your profile, but it will still show up for you for a while if you tick the "recently deleted" option, and it's always visible to moderators.

However, it's not indexed so won't be found by Google (or any other search engine) and won't turn up in any search results.